# I keep getting "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'vv'" message no matter what i try

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I've tried to run one of the codes from the Sebastion Rashka's book on machine learning using python, but using self.vv argument in one of the functions gets me message "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'vv'". Sorry, I'm new to this and my try of defining this argument's type failed. Please help.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
class Perceptron(object):
    def fit(self, X: np.array, Y: np.array, eta: float, iter_ep: int):
        np.random.RandomState(1)
        self.vv = np.random.normal(loc = 0.0, scale = 0.01, size = X.shape[1]+1)
        self.Error_total = []
        for i in range(iter_ep):
            error = 0
            for x, y in zip(X, Y):
                update = eta*(y - predict(x, self.vv))
                self.vv[1:] += update*x
                self.vv[0] += update
                error += int(update != 0.0)
            self.Error_total.append(error)
        return self
def predict(self, x_examples):
    return np.where(np.dot(x_examples, self.vv[1:])+self.vv[0] >= 0.0, 1, -1)
def plot_decision_regions(X, Y, classifier, resolution = 0.01):
    # initializing markers and color mapping for future usage
    markers = ('', 's', '^', 'o', '4')
    colors = ('red', 'blue', 'green', 'cyan', 'grey')
    cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])
    # getting the decision surface
    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min-1, X[:, 0].max+1
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:, 1].min-1, X[:, 1].max+1
    xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution), 
                           np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, apha = 0.3, cmap=cmap)
    plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
    plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())
    #Placing dots of the dataset accordingly
    for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
        plt.scatter(X[Y == cl], X[Y == cl], alpha = 0.8, colors = colors[idx], marker = markers[idx], label = np.where(cl == 1, 'verticolor', 'setosa'), edgecolor = 'black')
# Receiving dataset
s = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7/raw/0e7a9b0a5d22642a06d3d5b9bcbad9890c8ee534/iris.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(s, header = None, encoding = 'utf-8')
y = np.where(df.iloc[1:101, 4].values == 'setosa', -1, 1)
x = df.iloc[1:101, [0,2]].values
x = x.astype(float)
plt.scatter(x[0:50,0], x[0:50, 1], color = 'blue', marker = 's', label = 'setosa')
plt.scatter(x[50:101, 0], x[50:101, 1], color = 'red', marker = '^', label = 'versicolor')
plt.xlabel('sepal_length, cm')
plt.ylabel('petal_length, cm')
plt.show()
#Learning of model on the dataset
ppn = Perceptron()
ppn.fit(x, y, 0.1, 10)
plt.plot(range(1, len(ppn.Error_total)+1), ppn.Error_total, marker = 'o')
plt.xlabel('Quantity of epoch, units')
plt.ylabel('Quantity of updates, units')
plt.show()
#Visualizing the model
plot_decision_regions(x, y, ppn)
plt.xlabel('sepal_length, cm')
plt.ylabel('petal_length, cm')
plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
plt.show()
```

I've tried defining self.vv with different types as was recommended on other sites, but it didn't work. This message started appearing after I used this functions in a class, though they worked fine apart of the class 'Perceptron'.

Comment: Please include the complete traceback of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions `def predict` and `def plot_decision_regions` are not part of the `Perceptron` class. But looking at the function parameters, `predict` wants to be a method of `Perceptron`, as it has `self` as its first parameter, which is usually reserved to be a class parameter.
`predict` wants 2 parameters, `self` and `x_examples`. If it would be a class method, self would be the class instance itself.
You call `predict` inside the `fit` method of `Perceptron` and give 2 variables, `x` and `self.vv`. So inside predict, the variables turn to `x -> self` and `self.vv -> x_examples`, because that's the order and name `predict` expects as parameters. Remember that the `self` variable in `predict` was the `x` variable from `fit`. The error most likely comes then from `self.vv[1:]` (and also `self.vv[0]`) in the return call from `predict`, as `self` is the numpy array `x`.
You can solve this by calling

```
update = eta*(y - predict(self, x))
```

inside `fit`, handing the class instance to `predict` (assuming x is the expected `x_examples`).
Or you indent `predict` inside the class, and call it in `fit` with

```
update = eta*(y - self.predict(x))
```

which I would prefer, as I expect a function with `self` as its first parameter to be a class method.